# Can a spring kafka consumer run on multiple machines for the same groip?

Tags: spring-integration, apache-kafka

Kafka says that the offset is managed by consumers and there should be as many consumers as many partitions for the same group.
Spring integration says that the number of consumer streams in high level consumer is the number of partitions for the same group.
So, can the spring kafka consumer code run on multiple servers for the same group? If yes, how do the offsets know not to be in conflict between servers?

Comment: multiple consumers in one group？

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34988669/why-kafka-0-8-2-say-that-each-partition-is-consumed-by-exactly-one-consumer-in-a/35015126#35015126

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the kafka doc, if **group** (http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#introduction) was implemented, each message is consumed by exactly one consumer in the group. Each consumer can run on one machine. Two consumer can run on the same machine, also. In this case, each consumer can be one process.

One group can contain multiple consumers. Partitions can be distributed among all the consumers in one group by some algorithms. The number of consumers can be larger or less than the number of the partitions.

Offset can be managed by aid of zookeeper. but not all functions have been implemented in some clients until now.

As for your use case, in fact, kafka maybe "at-least-once delivery system". Kafka can be at-most-once delivery by disabling retries on the producer OR committing its offset before processing a batch of messages. It is very difficult to implement "exactly-once delivery system", which requires co-operation. But kafka provides offset. So it may be possible.For more details, please see http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#semantics, http://ben.kirw.in/2014/11/28/kafka-patterns/, https://dzone.com/articles/kafka-clients-at-most-once-at-least-once-exactly-o and so on.

Based on my personal experience, I spent lots of time to make sure that my kafka system to be exactly-once delivery system. but when the server is down, some messages can be consumed twice. But my testing was done on standalone kafka server, always kafka cluter is used in production. So, I think it may can be considered as exactly-once system.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, i would like to know more specific details for my use case: inside the same consumer group, with spring integration. How can we get the guarantee that the offset is managed only by zookeper with no overlaps?

Comment: It said one the consumer section here (http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#intro_consumers) that "Consumers label themselves with a consumer group name, and each message published to a topic is delivered to one consumer instance within each subscribing consumer group. Consumer instances can be in separate processes or on separate machines. "

Comment: In fact,  kafka maybe "at-least-once delivery system". It is very difficult to implement "exactly-once delivery system". http://ben.kirw.in/2014/11/28/kafka-patterns/

Comment: But try this https://dzone.com/articles/kafka-clients-at-most-once-at-least-once-exactly-o